# How does structure padding take place in the below snippet of code

Tags: c, structure, padding

I am using a structure, but unable to understand how the padding occurs. I am using a 64-bit system. The size of char is 1 byte, float is 4 byte and long is 8 byte in my system.

```
struct record{
    char name[50];
    float cost;
    long num;
}stu;

Size: 64.
```

This result in size of: 64

```
struct record{
    char name[50];
    long num;
    float cost;
}stu;
```

Size: 72.

I am not sure how padding takes place in both the cases.

Comment: You can use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro to find the byte-offset of each member, and see when and where and how much padding is added.

Comment: With that said, you usually don't need to case about it. The only time you do need to care about it is when using a raw binary protocol or file, where you want your structures to match the data of the protocol or files exactly. But then you should use packing directives and fixed-size types. So unless you're dealing with something like that, then I assume this question is just about plain curiosity?

Comment: The important lesson learnt here is to place large aligned objects like floating point or long at the beginning of the struct, then char arrays or smaller objects at the end. As written, you are forcing the compiler to pick an inefficient memory layout.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is used to maintain alignment of types.  Processors tend to be more efficient if 4-byte types are aligned on addresses divisible by 4, for example.

```
struct record {
    char name[50];  // offset 0 size 50 (type is size 1)
    /* padding 2 bytes here */
    float cost;     // offset 52 (size 4, offset divisible by 4)
    long num;       // offset 56 (size 8, offset divisible by 8)
} stu;              // total 64 (divisible by 8, (min of current packing size or largest member)
```

```
struct record {
    char name[50];  // offset 0, size 50
    /* padding 6 bytes here */
    long num;       // offset size 56, size 8, offset divisible by 8
    float cost;     // offset 64, size 4, offset divisible by 4
    /* padding 4 bytes here */
} stu;   // total 72, divisible by 8 (min of current packing size or largest member)
```

The trailing packing is needed in the case of contiguous arrays of structures to maintain natural alignment of types for each element of the array.